# Is there a way to disable the constant folding optimization in GHC?

Tags: haskell, optimization, compilation, ghc, constantfolding

I need to compiler some Haskell source code with GHC -O1 optimization but with the constant folding optimization disabled. I could not find an optimization flag for toggling constant folding in GHC manual however. Is this possible to turn off it meanwhile keep other optimizations?

Comment: I'm curious: what is your actual purpose? Why do you need to disable that?

Comment: @chi I am developing a compiler with Haskell and its functionality is quite limited at this moment. I first use GHC to parse the source program, which is in Haskell, to Core and then perform transformations on Core. I want to test the performance of the generated code for some examples whose arguments should be given at run time. However, right now the arguments need to be hard-coded and GHC folded all the constants so instead of getting the target code computing the result, I only get a constant value, which is not quite helpful.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you put those constants in a separate module and export those with a no-inline pragma, e.g. `module A where {-# NOINLINE #-} foo :: Int ; foo = 42`. Maybe it's worth a try, but I'm just guessing here...

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with `-fno-enable-rewrite-rules`, it disables constant folding.
Also, IMO if you pass the constants to a NOINLINE function and use them inside the function, you stand a good chance that it doesn't get folded.